# Bootstrap Carousel Modal Conversion

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I found this example of a bootstrap carousel slider with animated captions sliding up from the bottom of the image with a semi transparent background.

Here is a link to the original tutorial I found.
http://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/carousel-fit.html

Link to my demo http://bsdev.aowebsite.com/test.html

Couple of things..

1. This plugin seems to be built on Bootstrap2. Can anyone help me convert this to Bootstrap3?
2. How do I stop everything from moving except the slider? If you look at my demo, when the slide transitions, the next / prev arrows move up and down and the caption does some weird stuff like starts below the image before on initial load and then fades out to the lower left of the page.

---

```
(function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define([
            'jquery',
            'bootstrap'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(
            window.jQuery
        );
    }
}(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.extend($.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype, {
        fit: function (item) {
            if (this.fitting || !this.$element.hasClass('carousel-fit')) return;

            this.fitting = true;

            var
                that = this
                , slide = typeof item !== 'undefined' ? item : 'active'
            ;

            if (item != 'active' && slide == 'active' && this.$element.find('.prev').length) {
                slide = 'prev';
            }
            else if (item != 'active' && slide == 'active' && this.$element.find('.next').length) {
                slide = 'next';
            }

            var
                $slide = this.$element.find('.' + slide)
                , $img = $slide.find('img')
                , $caption = $slide.find('.carousel-caption')
                , e = $.Event('fit')
                , unfit = function () {
                    $caption.css({
                        'left': 0 || $caption.css('left')
                        , 'right': 0 || $caption.css('right')
                    });
                }
                , adaptWrapper = function () {
                    if (that.$element.height() != $img[0].offsetHeight) {
                        that.$element.animate({
                            'height': $img[0].offsetHeight
                        }, adaptCaption);
                    }
                    else {
                        adaptCaption();
                    }
                }
                , adaptCaption = function () {
                    $caption.css({
                        'left': $img[0].offsetLeft
                        , 'right': $img.parent().width() - $img[0].offsetLeft - $img[0].offsetWidth
                    });

                    that.fitting = false;

                    that.$element.trigger(e);
                }
            ;

            unfit();

            if (slide != 'active' && this.height) {
                this.$element.animate({
                    'height': this.height
                }, adaptWrapper);
            }
            else {
                adaptWrapper();
            }
        }
    });

    var _fn = $.fn.carousel;
    $.fn.carousel = function () {
        var result = _fn.apply(this, arguments);

        this.each(function () {
            var
                $this = $(this)
                , data = $this.data('carousel')
            ;

            if (!data.height) {
                data.height = $this.height();
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('carousel-fit')) {
                data.fit();
            }
        });

        return result;
    };
    $.fn.carousel.defaults = _fn.defaults;
    $.fn.carousel.Constructor = _fn.Constructor;
    $.fn.carousel.noConflict = _fn.noConflict;

    var _slide = $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.slide;
    $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.slide = function () {
        var
            that = this
            , result = _slide.apply(this, arguments)
        ;

        if (this.$element.hasClass('carousel-fit')) {
            this.fit(this.$element.find('.next').length ? 'next' : 'prev');
        }

        return result;
    };

    $(window).on('resize', function (e) {
        $('.carousel').carousel('fit');
    });
}));
```